# Detecting change to Knockout view model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Sure this is a very easy question to answer but is there an easy way to determine if any property of a knockout view model has changed?

Comment: Check out this post: [Creating a Smart, Dirty Flag in KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html)

Answer (score 101):

Use extenders:

```
ko.extenders.trackChange = function (target, track) {
    if (track) {
        target.isDirty = ko.observable(false);
        target.originalValue = target();
        target.setOriginalValue = function(startingValue) {
            target.originalValue = startingValue; 
        };
        target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            // use != not !== so numbers will equate naturally
            target.isDirty(newValue != target.originalValue);
        });
    }
    return target;
};
```

Then:

```
self.MyProperty= ko.observable("Property Value").extend({ trackChange: true });
```

Now you can inspect like this:

```
self.MyProperty.isDirty()
```

You can also write some generic viewModel traversing to see if anything's changed:

```
self.isDirty = ko.computed(function () {
    for (key in self) {
        if (self.hasOwnProperty(key) && ko.isObservable(self[key]) && typeof self[key].isDirty === 'function' && self[key].isDirty()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

... and then just check at the viewModel level

```
self.isDirty()
```

Comment: I recommend using `target.isDirty(!(newValue >= target.originalValue && newValue <= target.originalValue));` instead, `!=` doesn't work on Date objects.

Comment: Thanks for this example - I've been trying to find a way to do change tracking in such a way that the original value and the changed value could be displayed to the user.  If anyone is looking for the same, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dKk9P/

Comment: What if you don't have the value of the property yet?

Comment: You can hang another method off the extension called, say, 'setOriginalValue' that sets the extension's target.orginalValue internal property after-the-fact. That should init/setup things in a way that works.

Comment: Added the new method setOriginalValue to the code example since it seems helpful

Comment: setOriginalValue won't work as written, as dirty() is only updated when the _real_ value changes.  originalValue needs to be subscribed/observable as well. (or just make isDirty a computed directly)

Comment: That was intended as more of a way to set the initial starting value if the value is not set at the time of initial binding (based on comment/question from Jake Gaston)... in that case, you would not want that to set the dirty flag to true.

Comment: @TDaver that didn't seem to work with null values as the original and going to 0. Only 0 seemed to be the problem. Quick fix I implemented was null checked:
if (newValue === null && target.originalValue !== null)
                target.isDirty(true);
            else if (newValue !== null && target.originalValue === null)
                target.isDirty(true);
            else
                target.isDirty(!(newValue >= target.originalValue && newValue <= target.originalValue));

Comment: Excellent solution. If you also need to reset the flag after an event (for example, if the user "saves" the data), you need also: 
target.resetDirty= function () {
            var value = target();
            target.setOriginalValue(value);
            target.notifySubscribers(value);

        };

Answer (score 50):

You can subscribe to the properties that you want to monitor:

```
myViewModel.personName.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("The person's new name is " + newValue); 
});
```

This will alert when personName changes.

Ok, so you want to know when anything changes in your model...

```
var viewModel = … // define your viewModel

var changeLog = new Array();  

function catchChanges(property, value){
    changeLog.push({property: property, value: value});
    viewModel.isDirty = true;
}

function initialiseViewModel()
{
    // loop through all the properties in the model
    for (var property in viewModel) {

        if (viewModel.hasOwnProperty(property)) { 

            // if they're observable
            if(viewModel[property].subscribe){

                // subscribe to changes
                viewModel[property].subscribe(function(value) {
                    catchChanges(property, value);
                });
            }
        }
    }
    viewModel.isDirty = false;
}

function resetViewModel() {
    changeLog = new Array();  
    viewModel.isDirty = false;
}
```

*(haven't tested it - but you should get the idea)*

Comment: Thanks for the response - yes, was looking for something that would detect any change on any property, preferably using upshot properties - some how?

Comment: Ok - just got home - I'll put together a generic bit of code for you - I guess you want some kind of logging or Model.IsDirty solution?

Comment: That was the kind of thing I had in mind yes, thanks again for the help.

Comment: Very easy to understand answer

Answer (score 6):

Consider using [Knockout-Validation plug-in](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation)

It implements the following:

> yourProperty.isModified() - Checks if the user modified the value.
>
> yourProperty.originalValue - So you can check if the value really changed.

Along with other validation stuff which comes in handy!

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You might use the plugin below for this:

https://github.com/ZiadJ/knockoutjs-reactor

The code for example will allow you to keep track of all changes within any viewModel:

```
ko.watch(someViewModel, { depth: -1 }, function(parents, child) { 
    alert('New value is: ' + child());
});
```

PS: As of now this will not work with subscribables nested within an array but a new version that supports it is on the way.

**Update:** The sample code was upgraded to work with v1.2b which adds support for array items and subscribable-in-subscribable properties.

Comment: Hey, just wondering... did you ever get around to building the array functionality?

Comment: I made a few quick changes in knockout.reactor.latest.js hoping this will fix the array issue but I haven't had time to test it yet. So feel free to check it out for yourself and let me know if you're still having problems.

Comment: That's cool, I've actually been working on a similar piece of functionality and am going to blog about it soon so maybe we can compare notes.

Comment: The latest code should be good to go now. I'm tempted to release it as a stable version but I'd rather be more cautious than less and wait for some feedback first.

Comment: How do I get the name of the property that changed? In FireBug params is empty [], however, modifiedProperty has the new value. I just don't know which property changed.

Comment: I've just updated the sample code to match v1.2b that brought about some breaking changes. 'modifiedProperty'(now 'child') is the modified property actually which in turn contains the new value. So you don't need to look any further for it. However 'params' has become 'parents' which is just a list of all parents for the modified property. You might also want to tag each parent with their name for easy identification or keep old values for comparison or to allow undos. Those are supported as well and are documented in the <param> section of the source code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, i needed to observe any change on the viewModel, in order to send the data back to the server, 
If anyone still intersted, i did some research and this is the best solution iv'e managed to assemble:

```
function GlobalObserver(viewModel, callback) {  
    var self = this;
    viewModel.allChangesObserver = ko.computed(function() {
        self.viewModelRaw = ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel);
    });
    viewModel.allChangesObserver.subscribe(function() {
        callback(self.viewModelRaw);
    });
    self.dispose = function() {
        if (viewModel.allChangesObserver)
            viewModel.allChangesObserver.dispose();
        delete viewModel.allChangesObserver;
    };
};
```

in order to use this 'global observer':

```
function updateEntireViewModel() {
    var rawViewModel = Ajax_GetItemEntity(); //fetch the json object..    
    //enter validation code here, to ensure entity is correct.
    if (koGlobalObserver)
        koGlobalObserver.dispose(); //If already observing the older ViewModel, stop doing that!
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(rawViewModel);        
    koGlobalObserver = new GlobalObserver(viewModel, Ajax_Submit);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel [ ,optional dom element]);   
}
```

Note that the callback given (in this case 'Ajax_Submit') will be fired on ANY change that occurs on the view model, so i think it's really recommended to make some sort of delay mechanism to send the entity only when the user finished to edit the properties:

```
var _entitiesUpdateTimers = {};

function Ajax_Submit(entity) { 
    var key = entity.ID; //or whatever uniquely related to the current view model..
    if (typeof _entitiesUpdateTimers[key] !== 'undefined')
        clearTimeout(_entitiesUpdateTimers[key]);    
    _entitiesUpdateTimers[key] = 
        setTimeout(function() { SendEntityFunction(entity); }, 500);           
}
```

I'm new to JavaScript and the knockout framework, (only yestarday i started to work with this wonderfull framework), so don't get mad at me if i did something wrong.. (-:

Hope this helps!

Comment: funny, youre using knockout for faster use experience. Then on every change on the client you commit to server :) Youre better of with regular binding, simpler and easier ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've adapted @Brett Green code and extended it so that we can have AcceptChanges, marking the model as not dirty plus having a nicer way of marking models as trackables. Here is the code:

```
var viewModel = {
    name: ko.observable()   
};

ko.track(viewModel);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/david_freire/3HZEu/2/

Comment: the Fiddle dieded.

Comment: Must have been temporary.

Answer (score 1):

I did this by taking a snapshot of the view model when the page loads, and then later comparing that snapshot to the current view model.  I didn't care what properties changed, only if any changed.

Take a snapshot:

```
var originalViewModel = JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(viewModel));
```

Compare later:

```
if(originalViewModel != JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(viewModel))){
    // Something has changed, but we don't know what
}
```

Comment: for future reference, `JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(VM))` is same as just `ko.toJSON(vm)`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a view model as follows

```
function myViewModel(){
    var that = this;
    that.Name = ko.observable();
    that.OldState = ko.observable();
    that.NewState = ko.observable();

    that.dirtyCalcultions - ko.computed(function(){
    // Code to execute when state of an observable changes.
});
}
```

After you Bind your Data you can store the state using ko.toJS(myViewModel) function.

```
myViewModel.Name("test");
myViewModel.OldState(ko.toJS(myViewModel));
```

You can declare a variable inside your view model as a computed observable like

```
that.dirtyCalculations = ko.computed(function () {});
```

This computed function will be entered when there is change to any of the other observables inside the view model.

Then you can compare the two view model states as:

```
that.dirtyCalculations = ko.computed(function () {
  that.NewState(that);

  //Compare old state to new state
  if(that.OldState().Name == that.NewState().Name()){
       // View model states are same.
  }
  else{
      // View model states are different.
  }
```

});

**Note: This computed observable function is also executed the first time when the view model is initialized. **

Hope this helps !
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I like Brett Green's solution. As someone pointed out, the isDirty comparison doesn't work with Date objects. I solved it by extending the subscribe method like this:

```js
    observable.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            observable.isDirty(newValue != observable.originalValue);

            if (newValue instanceof Date) {
                observable.isDirty(newValue.getTime() != observable.originalValue.getTime());
            }
        });
```