# Is there a standard way of change tracking with a Knockout bound page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, knockout.js

I have a rather complex web page with various tabs, forms, radio buttons, drop downs, etc.  It's all bound using Knockout.js to a very complex JavaScript object that was loaded via an AJAX call.  Of course the user can muck with stuff to their heart's content, at which point they hit a *Save* button to persist all their changes back to the server.

I'm in the process of coming up with a good design to track exactly what was changed on the page so I can implement saving.  So, I've come up with a few possible implementations.

**Option 1) Just send everything back and let the server sort it out:** With this method, I'd let Knockout just update the data source.  The *Save* button would call `.toJS()` and send that data back to the server.  **Pros:** It's super easy, and takes very little work on the client.  **Cons:** The server doesn't really know what changed and has to either load the data from the database to compare, or just save all the fields again.  These fields come from multiple tables and have complex relations.  It also treats the entire document as a single atomic unit.  If someone else changed Field A and you changed field B, one user is going to lose their change.

**Option 2) Use JavaScript to compare the original data and the current data:** Using this technique, when the user clicks on the *Save* button, I would systematically compare the original data and current data and generate a graph of changes.  **Pros:** This would ideally result in a compact graph of exactly what the user changed, and could even no-op if nothing was changed.  **Cons:** The data I'm binding to is complex.  It consists of strings, arrays, objects, arrays of objects, arrays of objects with other objects, etc.  Looking for changes would be a rather complex nested loop.

**Option 3) Track changes as they are being made in the UI:** I would have to observe changes as they happen, and keep a delta as UI elements were changed.  The *Save* button would simply send that change graph to the server if it had any pending changes.  **Pros:** No need to compare two huge JavaScript objects looking for changes, but still has all the benefits of option 2.  **Cons:** Knockout doesn't *appear* to have a standard way to listen to all changes using a single event handler.  I believe I would have to resort to binding to all the UI elements, or creating custom `bindingHandlers` in Knockout to implement this real-time change tracking.

**My Question:**

My question is mostly for Knockout.js experts.  Is there a standard approach, or recommended guidelines to solving this obviously common scenario?  Is sending back all the data, even stuff that hasn't changed, a common design?  Or are people implementing custom change trackers?  Does Knockout provide any sort of framework that eases this requirement?

**Update:** Found [this thing](http://kochangetracker.codeplex.com/), not sure if it could be useful or if anyone has any feedback on it.

Comment: Having just gone through something very similar, I'd lean towards option 1. We went towards Option 3 and it ended in heartache. The other thing you have to consider is what if the user cancels their operation (if you allow this)? You have to have some mechanism to roll back changes. With option 1 you could ask the server for the old data (or do something more creative, since that seems excessive), or you could use a [protected observable](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html).

Answer (score 1):

If it's a question of enabling/disabling the Save button, allowing the user to navigate "from" that page/state, then you can check with the https://github.com/CodeSeven/kolite

check the knockout.dirtyFlag.js

Hope this helps.

Edit: remember that you should "never" trust the data coming from the "UI".  The real comparison and validation, ultimately goes in your "controlled" environment within the server.

Answer (score 1):

What I would probably do is take option 2 - the comparison itself can be as simple as stringifying the JS object and comparing it with a cached version of itself.

A few other options are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622707/detecting-change-to-knockout-view-model).

P.S. Maybe [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) can help you manage this monster of a JS object?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a change tracker extension for knockout that Pete Smith greatly expanded on...

Take a look here:
https://roysvork.wordpress.com/2014/01/12/tracking-changes-to-complex-viewmodels-with-knockout-js/

It works on the principle of extending the observable to track initial state vs. changes the user has made on the client. I think this works really great and can give users real-time feedback to know what they've modified. In practice, we actually implement a save panel that shows all pending changes and even lets them undo individual changes, all by using the change tracker's reusable capability.

```
ko.extenders.trackChange = function (target, track) {
    if (track) {
        target.isDirty = ko.observable(false);
        target.originalValue = target();
        target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            // use != not !== so numbers will equate naturally
            target.isDirty(newValue != target.originalValue);
        });
    }
    return target;
};
```