# Knockout : find out which observable triggerred computed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an object with multiple observables. Is there a way in a computed to know which observable changes, therefore which observable fired the computed?

Thank you in advance 
Matthew

Comment: There's a suggestion here to use an extender to determine whether or not an observable is dirty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622707/detecting-change-to-knockout-view-model This would allow you to check the observables that your computed is registered against.

Comment: What is it that you hope to achieve with this? Just wondering if there's another way to do what you want to do outside the computed

Comment: I ended up using the below solution as before I was using a computed that check each object and checked if the property has changed which was very slow so instead I subscribed each object at this way I do not need to check what fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without details of exactly what you are trying to achieve, I'll post this in the hope it might help.

A simple way to track changes is to use the `.subscribe` method on an observable you want to track. Each time the observable gets updated, this method will fire.

```
self.myValue = ko.observable('initial value');

self.myValue.subscribe(function (item) {
    alert('myValue has changed to: ' + item);
});
```

The `item` passed in to the subscribe function is optional, so you can use the new value if required.

Here's a simple example of it in use with a computed:

### [Sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ULfF4/2/)

**JS:**

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable('Mod');
    self.lastName = ko.observable('dinu');

    self.valueChanged = ko.observable('');

    self.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        var val = '';
        if (self.valueChanged() !== '') {
            val = ' (' + self.valueChanged() + ' Changed)';
        }

        return self.firstName() + ' ' + self.lastName() + val;
    });

    self.firstName.subscribe(function () {
        self.valueChanged('First Name');
    });

    self.lastName.subscribe(function () {
        self.valueChanged('Last Name');
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
    <input id="fname" data-bind="value: firstName" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
    <input id="lname" data-bind="value: lastName" />
</div>
<hr />
<div>Hello <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span></div>
<hr />
<div>Value Changed: <span data-bind="text: valueChanged"></span></div>
```

Comment: Than-you that's what I ended up doing.