# Knockout custom binding how to identify which observable fired update?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a custom binding that depends on two observables: `data` and `selected`. Think it as an elaborate table.

In the html it is called as:
`<div data-bind="myComponent: {}, data: myData, selected: currentSelection"></div>`

The `ko.bindingHandlers.myComponent` `update` function fires when myData and/or currentSelection change. How could I, inside the update function, decide which observable has triggered it? Because if myData changes I have to re-render the component, instead if currentSelection changes I have to only update which element is highlighted.

Is the [Knockout : find out which observable triggerred computed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753112/knockout-find-out-which-observable-triggerred-computed) the only solution?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Also I'm not sure of the triggering order of the cited solution. That is, is it guaranteed that `.subscribe()` runs before the binding handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's considered "bad practice", but I often bypass the `update` method by adding my own subscriptions in the `init` function...

This would allow you to create multiple separated subscriptions that perform the behaviour specific to a change in either `data` or `selected`.

I *think* this method makes you responsible for the disposal of the extra subscriptions, so you might want to do some extra checks for memory leaks..

In the example below you'll see a custom binding that only has an `init` function. In the `init` I retrieve two other bindings (`left` and `right` in my case, would be `data` and `selected` in yours). I define two separate behaviours for when these observables change. At the end of the `init` function, I call both once.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.myComponent = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    var changeLeftColor = function() {
      element.children[0].style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
    }
    
    var changeRightColor = function() {
      element.children[1].style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
    }
  
    var leftSub = allBindings.get("left").subscribe(changeLeftColor)
    var rightSub = allBindings.get("right").subscribe(changeRightColor);
    
    changeLeftColor();
    changeRightColor();
    
    // When knockout disposes the element (for example because 
    // it's in an `if` binding), dispose the subs.
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      leftSub.dispose();
      rightSub.dispose();
    });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings({ left: ko.observable(0), right: ko.observable(0) });


// Utils
function randomColor() {
  return "#" + Array(6).fill().map(function() {
    return "0123456789ABCDEF"[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }).join("");
}
```

```css
div > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div data-bind="myComponent, left: left, right: right">
  <div data-bind="text: left, click: left.bind(null, left() + 1)"></div>
  <div data-bind="text: right, click: right.bind(null, right() + 1)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly the right solution! Thanks. So seems the `update` method is useful just for the trivial cases. Or am I wrong?

Comment: For me, the `init` / `update` separation is more about clearly defining what is initialization logic that you only want to run once (e.g. adding event listeners). I would like to add though, that usually a custom binding should do *one* thing. If you're creating complicated state/render logic, you might be better off using a *component*. Another alternative for your specific case would be to use a `foreach` binding on the top level (bound to `data`), and a `css` binding on the selection level (bound to `selected`)

Comment: Currently I'm learning knockout on a realistic application. Components will be the next step. For now I have different view on the same data and with your suggestion I'm able to sync the user selection between them and encapsulate all the logic in a bindingHandler.