# Automatically update ChartJS with Knockout data-bind

Tags: forms, data-binding, knockout.js, chart.js

I am using ChartJS with forms. What I am trying to do is get the value from the field to draw the specific chart segment. I want to use Knockout data-bind to get the chart to refresh when the number in the field is changed.

For some reason when I input a number it does not refresh automatically. However when I input a number and click refresh in the browser the number has held.

Can anyone help me so that the bind updates in realtime?

```
<body>
    <form>
        <input name="ValueStream" id="ValueStream" data-bind="value: ValueStream, valueUpdate: 'input'"></input>
        <input type="text" name="ProductService" id="ProductService" value="200">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <div id="canvas-holder" style="width:30%">
        <canvas id="chart-area" width="300" height="300"/>
    </div>

    <script>
        var pAndS = document.getElementById("ProductService").value;
        var vS = document.getElementById("ValueStream").value;
        var polarData = [
            {
                value: pAndS,
                color:"#F7464A",
                highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                label: "Red"
            },
            {
                value: vS,
                color: "#46BFBD",
                highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                label: "Green"
            },
            {
                value: 100,
                color: "#FDB45C",
                highlight: "#FFC870",
                label: "Yellow"
            },
            {
                value: 40,
                color: "#949FB1",
                highlight: "#A8B3C5",
                label: "Grey"
            },
            {
                value: 120,
                color: "#4D5360",
                highlight: "#616774",
                label: "Dark Grey"
            }
        ];

        window.onload = function(){
            var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
            window.myPolarArea = new Chart(ctx).PolarArea(polarData, {
                responsive:true
            });
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Nothing updates the chart here, it is only drawn on page load. You can [subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to changes of your viewmodel, or write a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js only draws the chart when you call the method. You'll need some way of seeing when the observable has changed and then call the PolarArea method again. You could try something like what is mentioned here: [Detecting change to Knockout view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622707/detecting-change-to-knockout-view-model).

Comment: You shouldn't need to re-instantiate the Chart etc. There's an .update method available: "Calling update() on your Chart instance will re-render the chart with any updated values, allowing you to edit the value of multiple existing points, then render those in one animated render loop."

Comment: So the question is - how do you wire things up to run .update when the view model changes?